# Price Indexer Fluctuate the Product Count in Magento

Tags: magento2.3, indexing, algolia, catalog-product-price-index

We have been continuously facing issues of Product Fluctuation in our Production Environment.

We have our Magento backend and Front end uses React/Mobile App. We have an intermediate platform Algolia, to which we send Products to be shown in our frontend. We are using Algolia Extension for Magento and according to their recommendation, we have setup the settings.

Now, we get to know a fix pattern in our environment and when that pattern happens, our products gets deleted from Algolia (Also Magento products decreased/increased unevenly) and while we do full reindex of Algolia, they come back from Magento to Algolia. **So, Even if there is no Algolia, **we can still see product fluctuation in Magento itself.****

We do Price Full Reindex, twice a week. In this operation, we update the price in Magento through FTP upload and run the Magento Full Price Reindex command. When we run the Price reindex command of Magento, a giant data set gets piled up in Magento Price Indexing backlog as per the data we have uploaded in sheet. To update the price in Algolia, we do a Algolia Full Reindex from Magento, while the giant backlog of Price indexer in Magento clears up, suddenly, few products gets deleted from Algolia but they should not be deleted as they are not Disabled, Out Of Stock, VISIBLE and showing in Magento website.

**This same set of issues was also replicated some days ago when we had pure Magento Website. When we do price indexing, some products gets disappeared from Magento site or all of a sudden price of the products become 0. We had to do full Magento reindex to bring the price.**

[image: Price Indexer Giant Number]

Resolution Tried:-

1. We had followed https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html and taken down the catalog_product_price batch size to 1000.

   1. Does anyone here have face this issue?
   2. What is the recommendation of Price indexing and other indexing we should follow to avoid such issues?